# Libdx | Input Processor touchDown() not firing every click

Tags: android, libgdx

I am using an input processor for touchinput on a flappy bird like game. 
This works fine on my droid turbo, and a couple other newer phones. But with my two older tables, a xoom, and verizon tablet, touchDown occasionally doesn't fire. I should mention that the FPS is 60 throughout gameplay. Also, I use an inputMultiplexer which adds both the playerInput and hud/play stages. Could this just be a problem with older android? Any fix? I am sure it's not my code for the fact that it works on newer phones.

EDIT
I tried using Gdx.input.isTouched like so :

```
if(Gdx.input.isTouched()){
    if(!touched){
        jump();
    }
    touched = true;
} else{
    touched = false;
}
```

But it gives me the same results as input processor :\
This is not a problem with the jump method, as of right now it just prints "touched" to the console.

Comment: Not sure it will help, but perhaps you try a different approach to possibly avoid the issue.  Implement a listener instead of polling, something like this:
button.addListener(new InputListener() {
            public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
//stuff
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void touchUp(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
//stuff
            }

Comment: You can implement InputProcessor. Please check this [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39337922/detect-user-input-in-render-or-using-inputprocessor-in-libgdx/39341150#39341150)

Comment: the code you posted above works separately from your input multiplexer.

Answer (score 0):

it is the issue with the viewPort. that is the different phone has different screen size. please check the below link which will help you

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39810169/libgdx-text-not-rendering-properly-on-larger-screens/39946652#39946652
```