# LibGDX : How to move by touch?

Tags: vector, libgdx, touch, move

I'm making an Android game. I want to make it move like the picture. I think I need a different method than the method of moving to the touch position or the method such as the joystick, but I can't feel it. Any help would be appreciated.

picture :
https://m.cafe.naver.com/ca-fe/image-viewer?url=https%3A%2F%2Fcafeptthumb-phinf.pstatic.net%2FMjAyMTAxMjlfMTc4%2FMDAxNjExOTI4OTMyMzg2.VMZokPdJgqQxeY3USeAngZe37sQcsbzMgO0OAUdHJYEg.xH4Gg-0VXHAHrQc2qAru-YYLAkqRodC8vGcA0dWP3wIg.PNG%2Fsketch-1611925622755.png%3Ftype%3Dw1600&d=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your class that suppose to control movement should implement `InputProcessor` interface.

https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ci/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/InputProcessor.html

Basically, you have to provide methods which will be called when screen touching or dragging happens.

You'll get, as those methods parameters values of i.e. where touch happened, how much user dragged his finger and stuff line that.

Don't forget to set your new input processor class with

```
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor
```

Check also: [Detect user input in render() or using InputProcessor in libgdx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39337922/detect-user-input-in-render-or-using-inputprocessor-in-libgdx)

Comment: Thanks. I will refer to it.